# Django save() method filling a certain field with None when saving with same id

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, timezone

I have this model.

```
class Country(models.Model):

countryname = models.TextField(null=True)
countryincharge = models.ForeignKey(Employees, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null = True)
createdby = models.TextField(null=True)
createdtime = models.TextField(null=True)
modifiedby = models.TextField(null=True)
modifiedtime = models.TextField(null=True)
deletedby = models.TextField(null=True)
deletedtime = models.TextField(null=True)
isdeleted = models.IntegerField(null=True)
tenantid = models.TextField(null=True)
```

And create and update functions as following.

```
#Create
def countrycreate(request):

if request.user.is_authenticated:

    if request.method == 'POST':
        id = request.POST.get('id')

        modelwithdata = Country(
            countryname=request.POST.get('countryname'),
            countryincharge_id=request.POST.get('countryincharge'),
            createdtime = timezone.now(),
            createdby = request.user.id


        )
        if Country.objects.filter(countryname=request.POST.get('countryname')).exists():
            messages.info(request, 'Country already exists!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

        else:
            modelwithdata.save()

        return redirect('/admin/countrylistview')

 #Update
 def countryupdate(request):

if request.user.is_authenticated:

    if request.method == 'POST':
        id = request.POST.get('id')
        modelwithdata = Country(
            countryname=request.POST.get('countryname'),
            countryincharge_id=request.POST.get('countryincharge'),
            modifiedtime = timezone.now(),
            modifiedby = request.user.id
        )

        modelwithdata.id = id
        modelwithdata.save()
        return redirect('/admin/countrylistview')
```

The problem is when a record is created the createdtime value is saved as intended. But when running the update function the createdtime value is set to None. For unknown reasons. Other fields are working fine. The db is SQLite. Same behaviour happens when use `DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)` and `DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are creating a new object, first grab the original and change only what is required.

```
#Update
// Change this to get the object
modelwithdata = get_object_or_404(Country, pk=id)

// Change only the fields you need to
modelwithdata.countryname=request.POST.get('countryname')

modelwithdata.countryincharge_id=request.POST.get('countryincharge')
modelwithdata.modifiedtime = timezone.now()
modelwithdata.modifiedby = request.user.id

//Dont need this
//   modelwithdata.id = id
//Save the new model
modelwithdata.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `PUT` or `PATCH` method to update the data instead of POST

For your code we can also use `.update()`

```
# Update

def countryupdate(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            Country.objects.filter(pk=request.POST.get('id')).update(
                countryname=request.POST.get('countryname'),
                countryincharge_id=request.POST.get('countryincharge'),
                modifiedtime = timezone.now(),
                modifiedby = request.user.id
            )
            return redirect('/admin/countrylistview')
```